# Elasticsearch query with mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, mongoosastic

I am trying to do query like this:

```
Gym.search({
                    "query" : {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["multi_field"],
                            "query": req.query.q,
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
                    }
                    return console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
                });
```

But it returns:

> "status": 400,
>       "displayName": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[PzLsLPHfTMu68AQ94_Af8g][gyms][0]: SearchParseException[[gyms][0]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{\"query\":{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"multi_field\"],\"query\":\"LCC\",\"fuzziness\":\"AUTO\"}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[gyms] No query registered for [query]];
>   }{[PzLsLPHfTMu68AQ94_Af8g][gyms][1]: SearchParseException[[gyms][1]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{\"query\":{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"multi_field\"],\"query\":\"LCC\",\"fuzziness\":\"AUTO\"}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[gyms] No query registered for [query]];
>   }{[PzLsLPHfTMu68AQ94_Af8g][gyms][2]: SearchParseException[[gyms][2]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{\"query\":{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"multi_field\"],\"query\":\"LCC\",\"fuzziness\":\"AUTO\"}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[gyms] No query registered for [query]];
>   }{[PzLsLPHfTMu68AQ94_Af8g][gyms][3]: SearchParseException[[gyms][3]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{\"query\":{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"multi_field\"],\"query\":\"LCC\",\"fuzziness\":\"AUTO\"}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[gyms] No query registered for [query]];
>   }{[PzLsLPHfTMu68AQ94_Af8g][gyms][4]: SearchParseException[[gyms][4]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{\"query\":{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"multi_field\"],\"query\":\"LCC\",\"fuzziness\":\"AUTO\"}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[gyms] No query registered for [query]];
>   }]"

It works when I use CURL... Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 Gym.search({
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["multi_field"],
                    "query": req.query.q,
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            },
            function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
                }
                return console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
            });
```

Comment: I need your help with this :'( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878490/elasticsearch-query-dont-work-with-mongooseastic